# How to use ORDER BY for individual search result in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have done a small query in oracle to display the search results in a way that first matched WHEN clause results at the beginning and last matched WHEN clause results at the end. Now i want to SORT the first matched results in DESC order and remaining results are in ascending order.

Below are the sample data that is used.

```
CREATE table test(id int, title varchar(50), place varchar(20), 
postcode varchar(20));
insert into test values(1,'gatla51','hyd','31382');
insert into test values(2,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982');
insert into test values(3,'ravi32','ongole','41482');
insert into test values(4,'reddy42','guntur','31281');
```

This is the query i have done(of course some one helped as i am very new to oracle):

```
select title, place, postcode
from (select title, place, postcode,
             (case when postcode like '%9%' then 1
                   when place LIKE '%9%' then 2
                   when title LIKE '%9%' then 3
                   else 0
              end) as matchresult
      from test
     ) d
where matchresult > 0
order by CASE WHEN postcode LIKE %9% THEN ZIP END DESC
```

But this query is sorting all the results. How can i SORT individual result, suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.  Notice the ORDER BY clause:

```
select title, place, postcode
from (select title, place, postcode,
             (case when postcode like '%9%' then 1
                   when place LIKE '%9%' then 2
                   when title LIKE '%9%' then 3
                   else 0
              end) as matchresult                 
      from test
     ) d
where matchresult > 0
order by matchresult,
         (case when matchresult = 1 then postcode end) desc,
         (case when matchresult = 2 then place
               when matchresult = 3 then title
          end) asc
```

Comment: Thank you Very much fro your kind help

Answer (score 1):

```
select title, place, postcode
from (select title, place, postcode,
             (case when postcode like '%9%' then 1
                   when place LIKE '%9%' then 2
                   when title LIKE '%9%' then 3
                   else 0
              end) as matchresult
      from test
     ) d
where matchresult > 0
order by CASE WHEN MATCHRESULT = 1 THEN ZIP END DESC NULLS LAST,
         CASE WHEN MATCHRESULT = 2 THEN PLACE END,
         CASE WHEN MATCHRESULT = 3 THEN TITLE END
```